# Ionic/Angular PWA: how to maintain data in DataService after external link and return

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hyperlink, progressive-web-apps

I'm building an Ionic v6 / Angular PWA with the data stored in the Cloud in Firebase Firestore.  I have a data service that calls the DB to get several objects, including an array of puzzles that the user needs to solve.  In my data service I keep the list of puzzles, an object of all the application messages and text (so I can easily translate into other languages) and a local object array that keeps track of the player's progress.  Everything works fine.  In the riddle or question of a puzzle there may be an html link to an external source for the player to get clues to solve the puzzle.  I use an innerHTML construct for the puzzle question.  If there is an external link it will be an a ref= tag.  Since it's in the innerHTML the app code itself is not aware there is a link and doesn't "know" that the link is tapped/clicked.

So far so good:  the app displays the text with the external link and I can tap it and navigate to the external page.  However, when I return to the app using the BACK button the app goes haywire because none of the data in the DataService class is there anymore.  All the objects are undefined.  I really don't want to re-get the data from the cloud database, and I don't want to store all the data in local storage.

With a PWA, how do I navigate to an external link/webpage and return to the app with the local data intact.

thanks